# generate a random value and use it for validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to validate an input field for human behavior. Can I generate a random code in JQuery and then validate this value for input field?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
     Human Test  = 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 form-group"><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Human Test" class="form-control" name="value_num" required/>
  <input class="input" name="captcha_num_hidden_contact" id="captcha_num_hidden_contact" type="hidden" value=""/>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rivR.png)

Comment: you can do it, but it isn't how a captcha works. Including google reCAPTCHA would be a better choice.

Comment: alfredopacino@yes i know please see the updated question i am including image there can you check please, and if we can do like this then please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the complete solution. Anyway I advice you this is ok only for learning  purposes.

```js
function RandomNum(min, max) {
  return parseInt(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
let key1 = RandomNum(1, 10)
let key2 = RandomNum(1, 10)
$("#rnd1").html(key1.toString() + " + " + key2.toString())

$("#submit").click(() => {
  alert(parseInt($("#rnd2").val()) === (key1 + key2))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Human test <span id="rnd1"></span></p>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="rnd2">
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="validate">
</form>
```

Comment: alfredopacino@its not generating number

Comment: have you included jquery?

Comment: alfredopacino@perfect

Comment: alfredopacino@can you  show this error message on top of input filed, like required errro message showing

Comment: I'm feeling I'm doing your homework. I'm wrong, right?

Comment: alfredopacino @no its not home work . I am unable to  to do this so i ask

Comment: alfredopacino@@you there

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would have to do it in three parts:

1. Generate a random value (and display it somewhere)
2. Get the value of an input field
3. Compare the random value to the input field's value

Here's an example:

```
// generate a random string
const random = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5).toUpperCase();

// get the input field's value
const input = $('input[name="value_num"]').val();

// compare the two values
if (random === input) {
    alert("Input correct");
} else {
    alert("Input incorrect");
}
```

I want to stress what is already mentioned in the comments, **this is not the way to validate if the user is a bot or not**. There are better services such as [Google's reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3beta.html). A good rule of thumb is to not re-invent existing tools.